# What does this refers to in call()

Tags: javascript

```
function hello (val){

  console.log(this, val);
}

console.log(hello('jumbo'))

let obj = {
  'name':'Pranjal'
};

var h = new hello.call(this, obj)
```

Comment: Have you done any research? I would expect many guides to exist outlining how `call` works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the docs should be visit *before* asking a question.

Comment: The same thing it refers to outside `call` since it’s passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<script>
function hello (val){
  document.write('<br>'+this, val);
  //Focus here
  document.write('<br>Here'+this+'is referred to the function which is part of window object.')
  //In Object orienrted technology 'this' is used to refer the object/function under which//we are working. As here if we say this then it refers to the function hello which//is part of window object.
}
//See this is part of window object.
window.hello('jumbo');//Works
//Same as
hello('jumbo');//Works as well
//So this prints twice.



</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here 'this' is a keyword used to refer the exact thing under which we are functioning. As here this refers to the function hello() so document.write() or console.log() will show the [object Window].
Please refer Object Oriented programming concepts here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/

Comment: My doubt is that in function invocation this refers to global object but in case of .call(this), this would refer to global object or the function 'hello' scope ?

Answer (score 0):

call() can be used to invoke any function that it longs for, no matter even if it belongs to some other object.
Here hello.call(this) will send global object call().Check the code run it and read the comments.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<script>
//Meaning of call
var person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    fullName: function() {
        document.write(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName+'<br>');
    }
}
var myObject = {
    firstName:"Mary",
    lastName: "Doe",
}
//can use function of other objects.
person.fullName.call(myObject);//refers to object i.e there in call();

//Solution
function hello (val){
  document.write('<br>'+val+'<br>');
  document.write('Here'+this+'is referred to the function which is part of window object.<br><br>')
}
//Watch what it prints at 'this';
hello.call('||||||other thing||||||||');//other things is printed.
hello(',,,,,Some other thing,,,,,,');//but here 'this' prints window object.
hello.call('@@@@Hmm@@@');//Again prints which is there in call();
//So we can conclude
hello.call(this);//Here the window object that is passed is call() not Hello().


</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```